# widget.newButton shown in simulator but not on device

Tags: android, lua, widget, coronasdk

In corona simulator I can see the buttons, but on the actual device I don't see them.

not sure what's wrong, no errors in console.

[image]

```
    local function playBtnF(event)
        if( "ended" == event.phase ) then
            transition.to(menuScreenGroup,{time=0, alpha=0, onComplete=addGameScreen})
        end
    end

    local playBtn = widget.newButton{
        left = display.contentCenterX,
        top = 0,
        id = "playbutton",
        label = "Play",
        onEvent = playBtnF
    }
```

Comment: What is happening on the actual device screen, nothing?  Are you able to get the logs from the device?  (Using `adb logcat`)

Answer (score 1):

The usual cause of "It works in the simulator but not on the device" is due to a filename, like an image or scene that has a case sensitivity problem.  In other words, in the sim:

```
 myImage.PNG    and
 myimage.png
```

are the same, but on the device, the names are case sensitive.  This is 95% likely the cause.  However you won't know for sure until you look at your device's console log.  If you do not know how to do that, this tutorial can get you going:

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/09/tutorial-basic-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any background setup? Even if its just black rectangle? If so then you have to add all buttons and background in group and set the background to go back of the buttons.

Comment: But would this not cause non-response in simulator too?

Comment: Sometimes it works in simulator and doesn't work on device. I had same problem when I started with Corona. Worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it might help but your left / top values definitely wouldn't make the play button show where it's supposed to be on your screen, either simulator or device, unless you are putting the buttons inside a specific parent group.

Could you share a bigger part of the code to get a better idea ?

As it is, the play button would show on the upper edge of the screen, a little bit to the right.

Cheers